# Perl Package Manager (PPM) installing modules in C:\TEMP\perl---please-run-the-install-script---/

Tags: module, path, ppm

I am using ActivePerl and tried to install a module using PPM(Perl Package Manager)

The installation is happening in the folder `C:\TEMP\perl---please-run-the-install-script---/`.
Can anybody tell me why this is happening? And how I solve this problem so that the modules installing using PPM will move to the correct path(ie `D:\Perl\lib\`)

The Perl is installed in `D:\Perl\` 
The `D:\Perl\bin` path is configured correctly in `path` env.variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the ActivePerl zip file but have not yet ran the `install.bat` file - see https://community.activestate.com/forum/where-did-ppm-put-modules

Comment: Thanks Michiel for the Answer,But Where i can find the install.bat file

Comment: I don't know how you installed perl, but my guess would be it lives in `D:\perl\`

Comment: Ok,I can't find the install.bat ,I just uninstall the Perl and installed again using the .exe from the Activeperl site.and it worked.

Comment: I have one more question to you Michiel, Can you please tell me what is the use of PERL5LIB and PATH for Perl,I got really confused with the both.

Comment: It's an environment variable or configuration option that can point to the directory holding your perl libraries, see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT - typically you do not need to mess with this and it should *"Just Work"*.